# Can I trap an exception in a LINQ projection?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

Say I write a linq query for info about the hidden files on my C drive:

```
var q2 =
    from c in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\")
    where Regex.IsMatch(c, @"^C:\\\.")
    select c;

var q3 =
    from c in q2
    let info = new 
    {
        File = c,
        FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(c),
        FileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(c),
        CreatedUTC = File.GetCreationTimeUtc(c),
        AccessedUTC = File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(c),
        ModifiedUTC = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(c)
    }
    select info;
```

The above is an example of logic that might want to keep going when an exception is caught, but I don't know how to get that to happen in this style of C# programming (or if its possible).

Conceptually I want some kind of "continue" statement that can be put in the body of a catch block surrounding a LINQ query.

```
try
{
   // LINQ QUERY
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  Logger.Log("error...");
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the lazy nature of LINQ you might need to `try/catch` when you start consuming the iterator and not when building the query:

```
var q3 = ...

try
{
    foreach (var item in q3)
    {
        ...
    }
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

The [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) simply returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and no evaluation happens until you start iterating over it.

---

UPDATE:

To avoid breaking out of the loop if an exception is thrown you could do the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    var q = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x =>
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        return x;
    });

    using (var enumerator = q.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                bool hasNext = enumerator.MoveNext();
                if (!hasNext)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO: do something with the exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, that's not a way to continue the foreach loop :(

Comment: @Gabriel, see my update for safely continuing the loop even of an exception is thrown.

Comment: just curious - is your use of a using block here a style choice or does it serve a function?

Comment: @Gabriel, a using block always serves function => it ensures that the Dispose method of disposable resources is always invoked in order to free associated resources.